# Guarding against CTE infinite loops in JOIN condition considered bad practice?

Tags: postgresql, cte

In [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH), and pretty much everywhere else on the net, to guard against loops in recursive CTEs people use `cycle` column. The problem with this solution (as opposed to doing the `ANY(path)` check in join condition directly) is that the loop is detected in the iteration after which it's first encountered.

Is there any reason to favor the first approach as opposed to the second? Is it because you explicitly *want* that duplicate child row, for some reason, or is there some hidden side effect of the second approach I'm not seeing?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE folders (id INT, parent INT) ON COMMIT DROP;
INSERT INTO folders
    (id, parent)
VALUES
    (1, 1);
```

1. `cycle` guard as a column in parent

   ```
   WITH RECURSIVE tree (id, path, cycle) AS (
       SELECT
           id,
           ARRAY[id],
           FALSE
       FROM folders
       WHERE id = 1

       UNION ALL

       SELECT
           c.id,
           tree.path || c.id,
           c.id = ANY(tree.path)
       FROM folders c
       INNER JOIN tree
           ON tree.id = c.parent
       WHERE
           NOT cycle
   )
   SELECT * FROM tree
   ```

   results in duplicate row (unless we explicitly deduplicate):

   ```
   1    "{1}"    false
   1    "{1,1}"  true
   ```
2. or as part of the join condition directly

   ```
   WITH RECURSIVE tree (id, path) AS (
       SELECT
           id,
           ARRAY[id]
       FROM folders
       WHERE id = 1

       UNION ALL

       SELECT
           c.id,
           tree.path || c.id
       FROM folders c
       INNER JOIN tree
           ON 
               tree.id = c.parent AND
               NOT c.id = ANY(tree.path)
   )
   SELECT * FROM tree
   ```

   which does not result in duplicate rows (+ one less iteration):

   ```
   1    "{1}"
   ```

**Edit:** one possible benefit of solution `(1)` I'm seeing is when you need to know that there was a loop in the query.

Comment: So if you need that duplicate row in the result, use a `cycle` column. In all other cases don't, it's a bit cheaper.

Comment: I'm wondering why postgresql docs do it that way, pretty much canonizing it for everyone else to copy.

Comment: Probably easier to understand, and the difference in performance is small.